Powershell scripts calling other scripts across Windows Server Versions
I am finding some strange behavior between Windows Server 2016 and Windows Server 2019 when running Powershell scripts. Both servers are running the latest 5.1 Powershell version. I have a script where I pass some parameters to another another script and then run the other script. If I run my script on Windows Server 2019 and up the script loads the second script and runs it as it should when it is called. On Server 2016 or below it stops at the call to the next script and just sits forever. Main script runs as a Scheduled Task with highest privilege with an Administrator account. Consider the following code:
$ComputerName = "COMPUTER1"
@Params['Name'] = "$ComputerName"
$Location = "D:\NewScript"
Push-Location $Location
.\Nextscript.ps1 @Params
Pop-Location
Write-Host "Done"

Cannot find a difference between the Operating Systems to that is preventing NextScript.ps1 from running. Is there something I should be checking or am I calling the script wrong?

Is there something I should be checking reproduce the symptom independent of task scheduler.

@GregAskew I can get it work as my account but not the service account.
